# Error while executing UpsertData() function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to update a custmer profile from a landing page. When I executed the `upsertData` as follow:

```
%%[ upsertData('Custmer_test', 1, 'Email_Adress', "user@toto.com", 'First_Name', "nouveau") ]%%
```

I had the following error :

```
The function expression is invalid. See inner exception for detail.

Script: upsertData('Custmer_test', 1, 'Email_Adress', "user@toto.com" , 'First_Name', "nouveau")
Index: 6575
ListID: 28578

An error occurred when attempting to execute an upsertData function call. See inner exception for details.
upsertData Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in a non batch context.
Function: upsertData('Custmer_test', 1, 'Email_Adress', "user@toto.com" , 'First_Name', "nouveau")
```

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Can you post the data types and precision values for each of your DE columns?    Also what's the Primary Key?

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference but you are using `'` in some spots and `"` in others

Comment: The `"` is for the values of the different columns in the DE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have misspelled "Address", which may be causing you problems. 
Everything you reference in AMPscript needs to be spelled correctly otherwise you'll get these types of errors.

Comment: i have written it correctly

Comment: I have resolved it, the problem was on the `First_Name` column, i wrote it wrong. Thank you.